# JS: Добавить класс для поворота картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть боковое меню, при клике выдвигается его часть. Нужно сделать, чтобы картинка рядом (стрелка вправо) при выдвижении меню поворачивалась вниз с добавлением соответствующего класса.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu span').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".menu ul").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.arrow-svg-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Как добавление класса связано с картинкой рядом? Причём здесь смотрение вправо/вниз? И в чём именно трудности?

Comment: рядом с "Клик" стрелка ( она смотрит вправо), при клике на "КЛИК" меню раскрывается, и вот мне нужно что бы при раскрытие меню стрелка была вниз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Находим близлежащее изображение с помощью [`.siblings('img')`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_siblings.asp), затем меняем наличие нужного класса с помощью [`.toggleClass('arrow-svg-bottom')`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu span').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".menu ul").slideToggle();
    $(this).siblings("img").toggleClass('arrow-svg-bottom');
  });
});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.arrow-svg-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод jQuery [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) может принимать callback функцию, которая будет срабатывать когда анимация закончится.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu span').click(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    me.siblings(".menu ul").slideToggle(function() {
      me.siblings('img').toggleClass('arrow-svg-bottom');
      me.siblings('img').toggleClass('arrow-svg');
    });
    me.toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.arrow-svg-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Также Вы можете добавить классам transition и менять класс перед запуском анимации, а не после.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu span').click(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    me.siblings('img').toggleClass('arrow-svg-bottom');
    me.siblings('img').toggleClass('arrow-svg');
    me.siblings(".menu ul").slideToggle();
    me.toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 1s;
}

.arrow-svg-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик</span><img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например переключать (тогглить) класс

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu .pp').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".menu ul").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
    $(this).find(".arrow-svg").toggleClass("arrow-svg-bottom");
  });

    

});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-svg {
  transition:0.2s transform;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.arrow-svg-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик<img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg"></span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик<img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg"></span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="pp">Клик<img src="http://metallcenter.uz/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow-svg"></span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```